# Name of This Shape/Figure?

Tags: geometry

I was messing around with the Desmos Graphing Calculator, and I came up with [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x6iigdo03y) result. This is made up of multiple circles, but I was wondering if there is a specific name I should call this shape/figure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a finite version of the so-called [Hawaiian Earing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring). More pictures from [Google Images](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=hawaiian+earring&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj56ZGZ_v_SAhUJWLwKHZQ0D-4Q_AUIBigB&biw=1680&bih=914).

Comment: Are they geodesics in any hyperbolic models similar to Poincare disks or Klein's?

Answer (score 0):

These circles are all co-tangential at $(0,0)$ to x-axis. In this case $ r \sin \psi = c$ where $ c$ is uniformly incremented. $\psi$ is angle of radial line to the circle curve.